# Swagger UI OpenAPI 3, query parameters displayed as an object instead of value-changeable fields

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc, springfox-boot-starter

Previously in SpringBoot v2.5.7, I had this Spring REST controller method. It had a `TestCriteria` type DTO, as the path param.

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/test")
public void test(TestCriteria testCriteria) {

}
```

And the `TestCriteria` class was like this.
(`Language` is an enum that can take either `EN` or `FR`).

```java
public class TestCriteria {
    @ApiModelProperty(allowEmptyValue = true)
    List<Language> langauges;
    
}
```

I used Springfox Swagger (springfox-boot-starter v3) and the Swagger UI looked like this:

[image]

But later I had to upgrade SpringBoot to v3, and use Springdoc and OpenAPI v3 for Swagger. Now the `TestCriteria` class looks like this:

```java
public class TestCriteria {

    @Schema(type="array")
    @Parameter(allowEmptyValue = true)
    List<Langauge> languages;

}
```

Now Swagger UI does not display `languages` as a value-selectable field, but as an object.
[image]

I compared the generated OpenAPI definition as well and found,

**previous API docs -**

```yaml
  parameters:
    - name: languages
      in: query
      required: false
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
        enum:
          - EN
          - FR
      collectionFormat: multi
      enum:
        - EN
        - FR
```

**new API doc -**

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: testCriteria
    in: query
    required: true
    schema:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/TestCriteria'
```

Is there a way I can provide the previous Swagger UI view, where the user can select a value from the enum list, rather than getting user's input via an object representation?

Answer (score 5):

Finally got the Swagger UI displayed as expected.

[image]

In the controller method argument, we need to add the `@ParameterObject` annotation:

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/test")
public void test(@ParameterObject TestCriteria testCriteria) {

}
```

This is explained in the [Springfox to Springdoc migration doc](https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html):

> If you’re using an object to capture multiple request query params, annotate that method argument with `@ParameterObject`.